# How to proper setup setTimeout with recursively using React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, recursion, react-hooks, settimeout

I'm building a component that should show elements of an array, one per time and it shows the element for a period of time determined by the data. With the data below I would like to show textA for 5 seconds and then change to textB which I would show for 20 seconds, and then show textC for 10 seconds and start over again, showing textA and so on.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
const slides = [
    {text: 'textA, time_length: 5},
    {text: 'textB', time_length: 20},
    {text: 'textC', time_length: 10}
] ;
```

```
const play = () => {
    if (slides && slides.length > 0) {
      const playSlides = () => {               
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
          // update index
          if (currentIndex + 1 < splashes.length) {
            setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1)
          } else {
            setCurrentIndex(0)
          }
        }, slides[currentIndex])             
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      if (slides.length) {
        debugger
        play(slides)
      }
      return clearTimeout(this.timer)
  }, [slides])

  return <p>{slides[currentIndex]}</p>
}
```

Comment: i build something similar recently, one way you can do this is to just have a setInterval that updates a timer and depending on that timer's value you change the text. ex timer goes between 0-35 and text gets updated at 5, 25, etc

Answer (score 0):

This solution will show the `slide.text` every `slide.time_length`.
Notice that the 'loop' is achieved via the dependency `[currentIndex]`; in other words, every time the currentIndex changes, the `useEffect` will run once more, and will update the `currentIndex` after the next `time_length` seconds.

The calculation `(currentIndex + 1) % slides.length` will reset the index back to 0 if it overflows the array length (it's just a shortened version of your conditional, nothing special).

```
const slides = [
    { text: 'textA', time_length: 5 },
    { text: 'textB', time_length: 20 },
    { text: 'textC', time_length: 10 }
];

const TextSlider = () => {
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (slides.length) {
            const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
                setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % slides.length)
            }, slides[currentIndex].time_length * 1000)

            return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }

        return () => { }
    }, [currentIndex])

    return <h1>{slides[currentIndex].text}</h1>
}
```

Sometimes being less wordy can make it easier to see what's going on. Your mileage may vary -

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

function TextSlider ({ slides = [] }) {
  const [i, nextSlide] =
    useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (i >= slides.length) return
    const t =
      setTimeout
        ( nextSlide
        , slides[i].time_length * 1000
        , (i + 1) % slides.length
        )
    return () => clearTimeout(t)
  }, [i])

  return <h1>{slides[i].text}</h1>
}

ReactDom.render(document.body, <TextSlider slides={slides} />)
```